# Как изменить отображаемое поле?

Tags: youtrack

[image: Отображаемые значения]

По умолчанию перед задачей стоит первая буква и цвет приоритета задачи.
Можно ли отображать в этом месте значение другого пользовательского поля?

Answer (score 0):

YouTrack не поддерживает возможность управлять порядком этого поля (Priority) в однострочном режиме на странице /issues.
Изменение порядка полей в настройках проекта не поможет.
Можно лишь удалить поле Priority и тогда его просто не будет на карточке, но поставить вместо него другое перед issue ID нельзя.